# Serverless not including my node_modules

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, serverless

I have a nodejs serverless project that has this structure:

```
-node_modules
-package.json
-serverless.yml
-funcitons
   -medium
     -mediumHandler.js
```

my serverless.yml:

```
service: googleAnalytic

    provider:
      name: aws
      runtime: nodejs6.10

      stage: dev
      region: us-east-1

    package:
      include:
        - node_modules/**

        functions:
          mediumHandler:
            handler: functions/medium/mediumHandler.mediumHandler
            events:

              - schedule:
              name: MediumSourceData 
              description: 'Captures data between set dates'
              rate: rate(2 minutes)

          - cloudwatchEvent:
              event:
                source:
                  - "Lambda"
                detail-type:
                  - ""
          - cloudwatchLog: '/aws/lambda/mediumHandler'
```

my sls info shows:

```
Service Information
service: googleAnalytic
stage: dev
region: us-east-1
stack: googleAnalytic-dev
api keys:
  None
endpoints:
  None
functions:
  mediumHandler: googleAnalytic-dev-mediumHandler
```

When I run sls:

```
serverless invoke local -f mediumHandler
```

it works and my script where I included  googleapis and aws-sdk work. But when I deploy, those functions are skipped and show no error.

Comment: Where do you get the error? During deploy or during invocation? Do you see `node_modules` in the `.zip` file inside your `.serverless` directory?

Comment: there is no error, it just skips all the scripts i wrote that use the required modules

Comment: That could be because your `serverless.yml` (if what you posted above is what's inside) has incorrect indentations. Can you post it properly?

Comment: If `sls info` does not list your functions, then your `serverless.yml` has problems.

Comment: @dashmug it lists my functions and I checked there are no indentation issues. I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis, and this isn't being called just skipped in my script when I deploy. Even though I required it in my mediumHandler.js

Comment: Please update the code above then to avoid confusions. What do you mean by "this isn't being called just skipped in my script when I deploy"? What's the output of `sls deploy` and what are you expecting to see?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155290/discussion-between-dashmug-and-noor).

Answer (score 9):

When debugging `serverless`'s packaging process, use `sls package` (or `sls deploy --noDeploy` (for old versions). You'll get a `.serverless` directory that you can inspect to see what's inside the deployment package.

From there, you can see if `node_modules` is included or not and make changes to your `serverless.yml` correspondingly without needing to deploy every time you make a change.

Comment: turns out it really was including the node_modules, but do you know why it won't run any of the libraries I added in my node_modules

Comment: Do your functions work when invoked locally? What does `sls info` tell you?

Comment: yes, it works locally when I use the 'sls invoke local -f....' but when I deploy it doesn't work. And my sls mentions my function ( i commented out one of my functions) :

functions:
  mediumHandler: googleAnalytic-dev-mediumHandler

Comment: I have also run into this problem. And it looks like there still isn't a solution :(

Answer (score 2):

Serverless will exclude development packages by default.  Check your `package.json` and ensure your required packages are in the `dependencies` object, as `devDependencies` will be excluded.

Answer (score 0):

I was dumb to put this in my serverless.yml which caused me the same issue you're facing.

```
package:
  patterns:
  - '!node_modules/**'
```